# zeros of imaginary part of $\log(\Gamma(z))$

Tags: complex-analysis, special-functions, gamma-function

I want to discover if there exist a solution of the following equation:
$$\Im(\log(\Gamma(iy)) - y\beta = 0 $$
for $y\in\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$ and $\beta >0$

I already proved that if there is a solution $y^*<0$ then also $-y^*$ is a solution, but this do not help me with the general proof.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Which definition of logarithm are you using?

Comment: The branch cut is on the negative real axis, so Arg(z) is is $(-\pi,\pi)$

Answer (score 0):

If the function is $\ln(\Gamma(i y))$, a solution may not exist, because the imaginary part is negative for small positive $y$ and cannot be greater than $\pi$.

If $\operatorname{ln\Gamma}$ is defined as the analytic continuation of $\ln(\Gamma(z))$ from the positive real axis to $\mathbb C \backslash (-\infty, 0]$, then $\operatorname{Im} \operatorname{ln\Gamma}(+i 0) = -\pi/2$; $\operatorname{Im} \operatorname{ln\Gamma}(i y) \sim y \ln y$ at infinity; $\operatorname{ln\Gamma}(i y)$ is continuous on $(0, \infty)$.

Therefore $y = y(\beta)$ s.t. $\operatorname{Im} \operatorname{ln\Gamma}(i y) = \beta y, \, y > 0$ exists for any $\beta > 0$.